# Stationary types with non-stationary extensions

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete stable theory (say in a countable language $L$). Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a monster model of $T$ and let $A\subseteq{B}$ be a small subsets. Let $p\in S(A)$ be stationary. Let $q\in S(B)$ be be such that $q$ extends $p$.

If $q$ is an non-forking extension of $p$ it follows that $q$ is also stationary. This seems not to generalize if $q$ is a forking extension.

Given the above setup, what is an example of a theory $T$ such that $q$ is a forking extension of $p$ and $q$ is not stationary? I tried the usual "equivalence" class examples, but the ones I tried end up making $q$ stationary because of nature of the example itself. Examples like $ACF_0$ don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levon gave you an example in $ACF$. I'll give you an example in equivalence relations.

Let $E$ be an equivalence relation with infinitely many classes, each of size $3$. Consider the type $p(x)$ over $A$ which says that $x$ is not $E$-related to any element of $A$. This type is stationary. Now let $B = A\cup \{b\}$, where $b$ is an element of a class not represented in $A$. $p$ has a forking extension $q$ over $B$ which contains the formulas $xEb$ and $x\neq b$. This type is not stationary, because it is algebraic with two realizations (just like Levon's example).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the theories where each class is infinite. But there the type that extends $p$ by $xEb$ and $x\neq b$ is stationary. Is there an obvious way to tweak this so the type $q$ is not algebraic over $B$?

Comment: Sure: take two equivalence relations, where the first has infinitely many infinite classes and the second refines each class of the first into three infinite classes. I.e. Replace equality in the previous example by an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example in $ACF_p$ for $p \neq 2$. Let $A$ be a field and let $a$ be a transcendental element over $A$. Then $tp(a/A)$ is stationary. But $tp(a/Aa^2)$ isn't: it is isolated by the formula $x^2 = a^2$ which has Morley degree $2$. If you like to think in terms of extensions $tp(a/Aa^2a)$ and $tp(-a/Aa^2a)$ are two nonforking extensions of $tp(a/Aa^2)$.

Comment: Assuming the characteristic is not $2$ :0)

Comment: That's right, thanks!

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: Thank you! That's a really nice example.